# Edge for Android web-push npm subscribe/ returns endpoint from fcm.googleapis.com

Tags: android, firebase, npm, web-push

I am using node.js web-push, it's worked perfectly well for Chrome, Firefox and Opera on desktop and Android for a good while ... today I've found an issue though with the new Chromium version of Microsoft Edge:
On desktop, it works fine - the endpoint returned from subscribe/ ... generateVAPIDKeys() points to sg2p.notify.windows.com.
But on Android, the endpoint returned points to fcm.googleapis.com, which results in notifications being pushed to the wrong client (I also have the same PWA running on Chrome for Android - but I've unregistered its service workers while working on this issue).
It's as if node.js web-push app.post("/subscribe"... is mis-recognizing the requesting client - handling it as if it was Chrome instead of Edge. 
I've searched the node-modules for references to Edge (it finds the old edge|trident userAgent string, but this is in relation to colors), but found nothing there I could try to update.
I've also un-and-reinstalled Edge for Android with no change, and searched widely on the web but found no references to this issue.
Has anyone else encountered this?

Comment: Thanks, collimarco, for your comment. The problem is that notifications are sent but they do not arrive, but I believe they would if the endpoint was a Microsoft one. I am no expert here, learning by doing - I am reasoning that since in Edge on desktop the endpoint is to sg2p.notify.windows.com, and that works fine, and in Firefox on Android and desktop the endpoint points to updates.push.services.mozilla.com, and that also works fine, that the problem is that Edge on Android gets the FCM endpoint, causing it to fail. If my reasoning is wrong, please do try to clarify, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand what's the question / issue: what you describe is the normal browser behavior.

The browser is free to return any endpoint.

Also Edge on Android is a simple wrapper around Chrome for Android and that's why it returns an FCM endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

So, a whole day of testing and figuring on this concludes that the current versions of Edge for Android, probably being little more than a wrapper for Chrome as collimarco pointed out, doesn't support push notifications successfully, at least not with node web-push. I also tried disabling Chrome on my Android device, but that didn't help. Edge always gets an FCM endpoint rather than one from WNS, and if push notifications arrive at all, they are directed to the Chrome client, not the Edge client. On desktop, however, Edge notifications work perfectly, getting a WNS endpoint, not FCM.